# Right justified and left justified mode I2S

Tags: electrical-engineering

How can we check the Audio codec (wm8960) is in right or left justified mode  using raspberry-pi

I connected wm8960 audio codec to the raspberry pi and i recorded wav file i checked in the dmesg its default state is i2s mode but wm8960 codec support left or right justified mode how to change mode from i2s to left or right justified mod.

inserted link wm8960 data sheet url
[wm8960][1]
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1365067/CirrusLogic/WM8960/1

Please help in this

Comment: Then i ran this arecord -l command to check the weather its detected or not , and it detected
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: wm8960soundcard [wm8960-soundcard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 [bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: i attached link interfacing of wm8960 and raspberry pi and its user manual

https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/54/WM8960_Audio_HAT_User_Manual_EN.pdf

Comment: Hi sir thanks for your support

I gone through the Data sheet, but to change that bits we need to change in driver code 7h register value (The default value for 7h register is 0x000a).

I hardcoded that value and again i reinstalled the source code but whatever i changed in driver that is not reflecting in the driver code How to do it ?

Comment: I attached the driver code link please have a look sir

https://github.com/waveshare/WM8960-Audio-HAT

wm8960.c file have register details

Comment: Can you please point to the respective source file, and the location where you made the change?

Comment: @Rix, Did you recompile the code?

Comment: yes i recompiled.
In wm8960.c there is "wm8960_reg_defaults[]" function in 07h register in that im trying to change but when i recompiled the changes are not occuring.

i written some printk lines in driver code so whenever im making changes in dmesg im analysing weather the left or right justified mode set or not like that.

Comment: In wm8960.c  "wm8960_set_dai_fmt" in switch statement they mentioned i2s,left and right justified mode.

Answer (score 0):

Right and Left justification can be achieved by adjusting the first to bit of Register 7, which manages the digital audio interface formats. Below is register and its respective content.

[image: Register 7 digital audio interface formats]

The changes can be observed on the I2S signal pins. A right justified mode should look like the following

[image: Right justified data]

Left Justified mode should look like the following.

[image: Left Justified Data]

Investing in digital data analyzer might be very beneficial. I have used [analog discovery](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/test-and-measurement/analog-discovery/start).

[image: Analog Discovery]

There is newer versions available.

Looks like [Saleae](https://www.saleae.com/) supports I2S. Might want take look at this device.

[image]

Either of these device will do the job. There are other in the market that might be better, or appropriate for your budget.

**Reference:**

- [Cirrus Logic WM8960 98/95 dB Stereo Codec with Class D Speaker Driver](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8960_v4.4.pdf)
- [Analog Discovery I2S Analyzer Trouble Shooting](https://forum.digilentinc.com/topic/20204-analog-discovery-i2s-analyzer-trouble-shooting/)
- [Using the I2S / PCM Analyzer](https://support.saleae.com/protocol-analyzers/analyzer-user-guides/using-i2s-pcm)
- [Interfacing an I2S Device to an MSP430 Device](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa449a/slaa449a.pdf)